# How did Owen know where to go?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

In new movie *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom* (2018), Chris Pratt's character Owen

> kicks in Maisie's bedroom door just in time to save Maisie from being eaten by the new dinosaur, the Indo-Raptor that has chased her by climbing over a rooftop.

Prior to this, Maisie, Owen and Claire were all downstairs trying to avoid being eaten, when they tell Maisie to run.  It takes a minute or so before Owen is able to follow after her and the dinosaur chasing her.

Maisie runs

> upstairs to her bedroom and hides under her bedcovers, while the indo-raptor climbs in the bedroom window to get to her.

Given the size of the house, the amount of noise (bearing in mind the dinosaur was outside rather than in the house) and the time taken to follow after Maisie, how did Owen know where to go to find her in order to save her?  Did I miss something in the scene that told Owen where he needed to go?

Comment: I think the scene is created such to have a thrilling effect and probably lacks thorough sequencing. Possibly plot hole. If you deep dive you would find plenty in this movie.

Answer (score 0):

Owen appears to have heard the Indoraptor entering and moving around in the room. He kicks in the door with the intention of killing the dinosaur (with his newly-acquired rifle) rather than specifically going in there to rescue Maisie who, as you've noted, is being quiet and staying out of sight.

> Following her scent, the Indoraptor found his way into the dark
> bedroom. Maisie tried not to breathe as the predator moved slowly
> across the room, drawing closer and closer. When the terrible creature
> was just inches away, Owen flung open the door, armed with the dead
> guard’s rifle. The Indoraptor spun to face him.
>
> “Maisie, get down!” he shouted.
>
> <sub><sup>[Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom - The Junior Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/37585114)</sup></sub>